# Why PyTorch optimizer might fail to update its parameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to do a simple loss-minimization for a specific variable `coeff` using PyTorch optimizers. This variable is supposed to be used as an interpolation coefficient for two vectors `w_foo` and `w_bar` to find a third vector, `w_target`.

```
w_target = `w_foo + coeff * (w_bar - w_foo)
```

With `w_foo` and `w_bar` set as constant, at each optimization step I calculate `w_target` for the given `coeff`. Loss is determined from `w_target` using a fairly complex process beyond the scope of this question.

```
# w_foo.shape = [1, 16, 512]
# w_bar.shape = [1, 16, 512]
# num_layers = 16
# num_steps = 10000

vgg_loss = VGGLoss()

coeff = torch.randn([num_layers, ])
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([coeff], lr=initial_learning_rate)

for step in range(num_steps):
    w_target = w_foo + torch.matmul(coeff, (w_bar - w_foo))
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    target_image = generator.synthesis(w_target)
    processed_target_image = process(target_image)
    loss = vgg_loss(processed_target_image, source_image)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

However, when running this optimizer, I am met with `query_opt` not changing from one step to another, optimizer being essentially useless. I would like to ask for some advice on what I am doing wrong here.

Edit:
As suggested, I will try to elaborate on the loss function. Essentially, `w_target` is used to generate an image, and VGGLoss uses VGG feature extractor to compare this synthetic image with a certain exemplar source image.

```
class VGGLoss(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device, vgg):
        super().__init__()
        
        for param in self.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = True

        self.vgg = vgg # VGG16 in eval mode
        
    def forward(self, source, target):
        loss = 0 
        source_features = self.vgg(source, resize_images=False, return_lpips=True)
        target_features = self.vgg(target, resize_images=False, return_lpips=True)
        loss += (source_features - target_features).square().sum()

        return loss
```

Comment: You should try to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your chances of getting meaningful feedback. We cannot replicate the issue you are reporting because we don't know what `calculate_synthesis_loss` is. Replacing with any off-the-box loss function and random tensors, I can get this to work by setting `coeff=torch.randn([num_layers,], requires_grad=True)`

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos Thank you for the commentary, much appreciated. I fear that even for a minimal example, including necessary code for image generation, image processing and GAN operations would be excessive. However, in edited OP there is now an elaboration on VGGLoss that I use, which might be somewhat helpful.